# Rails has_many NameError: uninitialized constant despite proper naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I suspect that this error is due to Rails naming convention pluralization stuff but I really can't seem to find the issue after searching through many other posts, why am I getting the below error?

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CHC::OrderItem::OrderAo
```

models/chc/order.rb

```
class CHC::Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

  has_many :order_items, foreign_key: :chc_order_id
end
```

models/chc/order_item.rb

```
class CHC::OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order

  has_many :order_aoes, foreign_key: :chc_order_item_id
end
```

models/chc/order_aoe.rb

```
class CHC::OrderAoe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_item
end
```

I have created the order, order item, and order AOE with their foreign keys filled out.

However, if I try to run, for example, `CHC::OrderItem.first.order_aoes` in the console, I am greeted with the error above. I'm assuming from the fact that the "uninitialized constant" is incomplete and has just "OrderAo", it's something to do with the pluralization of OrderAoe, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually fix this issue by defining the namespace properly:

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
> nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
> constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
> module nesting at the point of definition.
> - [The Ruby Style Guide](https://Define%20(and%20reopen)%20namespaced%20classes%20and%20modules%20using%20explicit%20nesting.%20Using%20the%20scope%20resolution%20operator%20can%20lead%20to%20surprising%20constant%20lookups%20due%20to%20Ruby%E2%80%99s%20lexical%20scoping,%20which%20depends%20on%20the%20module%20nesting%20at%20the%20point%20of%20definition.)

This suprising namespace lookup in your case is that you would think that:

```
class CHC::Order < ApplicationRecord
  OrderItem 
end
```

Would resolve to `CHC::OrderItem` since they should be in the same module. But it doesn't since you're not reopening the module and setting the module nesting. Instead it will just look for `::OrderItem` and you'll get a missing constant error.

If you just change the code to:

```
module CHC
  class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client # is this column really client_id?
    has_many :order_items, foreign_key: :chc_order_id
  end
end

module CHC
  class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
    # you need to configure the non-standard foreign key here as well
    belongs_to :order, foreign_key: :chc_order_id

    has_many :order_aoes, foreign_key: :chc_order_item_id
  end
end

module CHC
  class OrderAoe < ApplicationRecord
    # you need to configure the non-standard foreign key here as well
    belongs_to :order_item, foreign_key: :chc_order_item_id
  end
end
```

And define an inflection for the acronym that Rails doesn't know how to pluralize:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.singular 'order_aoes', 'order_aoe' 
  # shouldn't this actually be capitalized as an acronym?
  # inflect.acronym 'OrderAOE'
  # inflect.acronym 'OrderAOEs'
end
```

Then it just works because you'll actually be looking up those constants in the current module nesting.

Comment: @WillDeBernardi A linter such as [`rubocop`](https://docs.rubocop.org) will warn you about subtle issues like this. And there is [an extension specifically for Rails](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/).

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Honestly, I've just been using the scope resolution operator, since that seems the be the most common method through the codebase (i'm a junior with no idea what i'm doing) but i see why that exists in the style guide. thanks!

One question, why does the belongs_to also need the foreign key definition? Seems to work without it, can't seem to find that in the documentation.

Comment: Because it assumes that the database column will be named `order_id` and not `chc_order_id`. It's solely based on the name of the association.  It's in the [API docs]( https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) under options. "Seems to work without it" - your test isn't good enough. The belongs-to association will not work with non-standard foreign keys without it but you won't notice it if you're just using the has_many association.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're correct, Rails is trying to [singularlize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize) `order_aoes` and is coming up with `order_ao`. You can verify this with `'order_aoes'.singularize`.

You can fix this by explicitly supplying the class to [`has_many`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

```
has_many :order_aoes,
  foreign_key: :chc_order_item_id,
  class_name: 'CHC::OrderAoe'
```

Alternatively, you can teach [ActiveSupport::Inflector](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) the proper inflection in `config/application.rb`.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.singular 'order_aoes', 'order_aoe'
end
```

Comment: Yep, this solved it, thanks! As much as I can appreciate the "Rails magic" that happens behind the scenes for things like this, it sure can be frustrating sometimes.

Comment: While this does fix the immediate problem you're still plastering over a bug by providing an explicit class name instead of just fixing the issues caused by using the scope resolution operator instead of explicit nesting.

Comment: @max Yes, they should be nesting, but that doesn't solve the inflection problem; they're two separate issues.